# getting the random number generator to remove a choice once the selection has been made? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, random

I just wanted to start by saying that I have been searching though this (and a few other) site for the last 3 hours to no avail, i have read every post i could find in regards to my topic and either it did not apply or i couldn't quite understand what was happening.

I'm having 2 issues.

1. I can't seem to get the random number generator to discard a choice once it has been made.
2. My second issue is that there can only be one six point round per competition, and i cant seem to figure out how to limit it only to one with the specific constraints of a 6 point round.

The program is designed to simulate picking the jumps for a
    skydiving competition. There are three separate competitions
    (A,AA,AAA) (levels of difficulty, certain moves do not appear A or
    AA, AAA is all inclusive) that the user can pick from as well as
    whether the individual competition will be 6 or 10 rounds (A will
    always be 6 rounds). Once the user has picked the competition and
    number of rounds, the program is supposed to output the individual
    moves to be completed for each round as well as the points for the
    round (does this for all 6 or 10 rounds of the competition). Here is
    where my first issue lies:

Once a move is picked, it cannot be
    used again for the rest of the competition. I cannot for the
    life of me figure out how to do this.

Moving on, there are two
    separate categories for scoring, the numbered moves (1-22 in my
    program) and the lettered moves (23 and up), the numbered are worth
    2 points and the lettered are worth 1. each round is 5 or 6 points

The issue i am having with this is for there to be a 6 point round, it can only be made up of 3 numbered moves, no other
    combination would be acceptable; and to add to that, there can only
    be one six point round in the entirety of the competition.*

```
     for(int i=0; i < round; i++ )
     {
        System.out.printf("\nRound %d:\n", i+1);
        point = 0;

        while(point < 5)   
        { 
        pickedRandom=false;  
        formation = myRandom.nextInt(38) + 1;

            while(formation == 31) 
            {
                formation = myRandom.nextInt(38) + 1;
            }

            if(point == 4 && pickedRandom && formation < 23 )       
            {
                while(formation < 23)
                formation = myRandom.nextInt(38) + 1;
            }

            if(formation < 23)
            {
                point+=2;                   
            }
            else
            {
                pickedRandom=true;
                point++;

            }

            formationRound.set( formation, true );

            if(formation > 22)
            System.out.printf(" %s %s ",randomLetter(formation), formationName(formation));

            else
            System.out.printf(" %d %s", formation, formationName(formation)); 

         }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf( " %s \n", point );    
    }
}
```

Comment: a block of text telling a story - no question - no idea what is going wrong with your code see [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Welcome to SO.  That is a very long description for someone to digest.  Have you run your code through a debugger?  That is the first thing to do.

Comment: suppose you post your issues in minimal description with relevant code segment rather than whole senario.

Comment: Hey everyone, my only reason for posting the full code and the lengthy description is because i honestly dont know how to describe my issue without going in-depth with my explanation, i will reduce the code to the segment that is giving me issues. what i currently have will run and no issues are flagged. no matter what i have tried, i cannot get the program to limit the output to one 6 point round per competition, and i have not been able to find a way to have my random number generator  mark its selection as unavailable for the next time it runs.

Comment: hopefully the edits help. the path i have been trying to take in regards to preventing the random number generator from being able to pick a move twice is to set that move to true once it is picked, but either it is just some simple mistake i am making or its just something i do not have the knowledge yet, no matter what i have done, i cant get the program to cooperate. i dont even know where to begin to get the program to only output one 6 point round per competition. @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question due to formatting, your problem domain, or your code.

However I think you state you want to randomize some numbers, without replacements.

Some strategies to do so are:

1. Create a list of numbers, then shuffle it, pop a number off each time you need a random number, until your 'deck' is empty.
2. Maintain a set of numbers that have already been drawn. if the number is in the set, randomize another.

The lazy/brute force method of matching the 6 point round constraint would be to build your formations + competition in advance, in it's entirety. Check to see if it matches your constraints, if not, regenerate the whole competition.

This is only really economical in terms of performance if the chances of your constraints being invalid are fairly low. < 30-40%

Otherwise, you could regenerate only the current formation, but you would need to check that there are still possible valid formations remaining. I'm also not sure how badly this would affect your distribution of random formations.

Comment: Thank you for the response, is there any way you could help me to figure out how to go about that. I am in a Java 1 class so my knowledge is fairly limited in this regard. i have the program successfully generating random numbers (moves), i just dont know how to go about removing that number from the set once it has been picked. i have tried  having the program change the number (move) from false to true once it has been picked, but it has not worked so far.

Comment: for the other half of my question,  i have the program functioning in regards to the stipulations around a 6 point round, but i dont know how to go about limiting it to one 6 point round per competition (rounds can be 5 or 6 points). hopefully that helps to clarify a bit.

Comment: Is the 6 point round guarantee'd? or is it a possible random occurrence?

Comment: it is only a possibility, sorry for not specifying